# videojs full screen css

Tags: javascript, html, css, video.js

Hello I trying to fix css thats only issue is present in full screen as videojs does have css for full screen but I been trying to bypass the width

for the main progress bar I use the following

```
.vjs-cinematography-skin .vjs-progress-control {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #666;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  right: 0;
  width: 55%;
  font-size: 0.3em;
  height: 2em;
  /* Set above the rest of the controls. *///
  top: 4em;

  /* Shrink the bar slower than it grows. *///
  .transition(all 0.4s);
}
```

but I trying change this using fullscreen for debug reasons I added color

```
.vjs-cinematography-skin .vjs-progress-control .vjs-fullscreen .vjs-fullscreen-control div {
width: 100% !important;
background-color: #FFF !important;
}
```

but I have tried many ways I nor sure how to bypass the css for fullscreen only

here is my demo link

http://muse4u.tv/dev/dist/demo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone that needs to know you can bypass the css like this took me a while to figure it out :)

```
.vjs-cinematography-skin.vjs-fullscreen .vjs-progress-control { width: 86% !important; }
```